# Terminating a third-party application like the button "App Info -> Force stop" does

Tags: android

I can terminate my application like this:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

How can I terminate any application (or only the ones which allow to do that) much like the button `App Info -> Force stop` does?

Comment: Do you want to terminate other apps or just put those apps to background?

Comment: @phuc_tran what do you think based on what I've written in my question?

Comment: I just want to know the context where you want to do that. In some cases, terminating is not only solution :)

Comment: @phuc_tran, in my case it is.

Comment: handle the lifecycle of the activities terminating an application is not a good idea. Check this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238

Comment: @Raghunandan, the questions is not whether or not it's a good idea.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp i am not sure why you require this. I have not come across such a situation. So in what situation you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you cannot kill the processes your application has not created. For processes started by your application you can kill them by using

```
public static final void killProcess (int pid)
```

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#killProcess%28int%29)

If you want to kill background processes you can do

```
public void killBackgroundProcesses (String packageName)
```

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#killBackgroundProcesses%28java.lang.String%29)

But you will need `KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES` permission for that.

AFAIK this will just kill the process, but it won't kill the task in memory. So when the app is restarted, the activity stack/task will get re created from last time unless ofcourse the system itself kills it for freeing up the resources.

So AFAIK you can never achieve the same effect as `App Info -> Force stop` programmatically because there is no way to clear tasks in the memory and only system can do that.

Comment: And if I grant my application the permission "Device administrator"?

Comment: If your app is a system app or have those permissions then yes you might be able to do that.

Comment: More specifically you will need `android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES` permission and your app should be signed by system key.

Comment: So which one do I have to call regardless whether the process in background or not to kill it for sure given I have enough permissions: killProcess or killBackgroundProcesses?

Comment: You will have to use `ActivityManager.forceStopPackage()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use that code to get Aplicattion PID.

```
 /**
 * Gets the process pid.
 *
 * @param processName the process name
 * @return the process pid
 */
public static int getProcessPid(String processName, Context context) {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procList = null;
    int result = -1;

    procList = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for (Iterator<RunningAppProcessInfo> iterator = procList.iterator(); iterator
            .hasNext();) {
        RunningAppProcessInfo procInfo = iterator.next();
        if (procInfo.processName.equals(processName)) {
            result = procInfo.pid;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```